# Difference between "turns out that" and "turns out to be"

Tags: usage

E.g:

> 1. Turns out that it was a conspiracy against him.
> 2. It turned out to be a conspiracy against him.

I'm confused here in the usage of these phrasal verbs.

Comment: why post this twice?

Comment: I feel you're looking at the wrong part of the sentence. The comparison is between 'that it was' & 'to be'. 'Turns/ed out' is a red herring.

Comment: I posted this question here because i was told to. But i dont know how to delete the same question from the other website, sorry

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, these forms of the phrasal verb have the same meaning:

> [B2 *to be known or discovered finally and surprisingly:*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/turn-out)
>   [+ to infinitive] The truth **turned out** *to be* stranger than we had expected.
>   [+ that] It **turns out** *that* she had known him when they were children.

The first form takes the infinitive (not necessarily **to be**), the second form uses the conjunction **that**.

The Macmillan Dictionary [provides a use](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-out) in which the infinitive is not **to be**:

> The tape **turned out** *to contain* vital information.

So your sentences are almost identical in meaning:

> (It) **turns out** *that* it was a conspiracy against him.
>   It **turned out** *to be* a conspiracy against him.

In the first sentence, I've just learned that it was a conspiracy, or I'm sharing the news with someone who did not know this previously.

In the second sentence, I tell that at some past moment it became known that some thing turned out to be a conspiracy against "him".

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that in OP's first example...

> 1: *"It turns out that it was a conspiracy against him"*

...the first ***it*** is a true ***dummy*** "it" (it doesn't actually refer to any identifiable noun).

---

On the other hand, in OP's second version...

> 2: *"It turns out to be a conspiracy against him"*

...that ***it*** is syntactically the same as the *second* ***it*** in #1 - effectively a standard pronoun usage "forward-referencing" ***a conspiracy***.

---

It might be easier to see the difference if you compare similar constructions where the "true pronoun" stands in for an actual person (***he/she***, as opposed to ***it***)...

> 3: ***It*** turned out **he** was a liar
>    4: ***He*** turned out to be a liar

---

Also note the [whiz-deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24650) in my example #3 (relative pronouns such as *which, who, that* are normally "optional" in such constructions, and can thus be "deleted").